# C# WinForm - How to make TreeVIew node/child by text in textbox?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, textbox

Hi I have created an app in C# WinForm to generate HTMLCodes, Now I have a TreeView, Textbox that has text
I want to make node when you write in textbox create node in TreeView like that:

[image]

[image]

I have no Idea to this, I thought about checking if textbox contains a first and last character so and make a node on between them

Comment: Any kind of implementatin you want to do will require parsing the text to understand the structure of the HTML so you can create the right tree structure. Parsing HTML is not something I suggest you try and do from scratch - you can use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) or even just read the HTML as simple XML using something like [XDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netcore-3.1). Once you've parsed it into an object, you can write code to build the tree based on the structure exposed by the parsed object.

Comment: Okay, It's like on every <anystring> is in the textbox then add node to treeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stack (LIFO) and search first '<' and then first '>' to reach a tag (for example `tag1`). Search for its end-tag (i.e. `</tag1>`) and if exist, store this tag in the stack, add it to the tree and search about another and another tags. If an end-tag is reached, compare it with last stored tag. If end-tag is related to `tag1` clear it from stack. Until `tag1` is not cleared from stack, each tag that be found, is child of it.